# need to change time value stored in VARCHAR column

Tags: mysql, eav

I am using freeradius base billing system which is using mysql as its backend DB engine. Table structure is as follows,

[image]

Thousands of users account expiration is stored in VARCHAR column and I cannot change its column type because in this table some other information is stored in varchar as well. EXample:
[image]

. Date is stored in below format (in VARCHAR column)

```
29 Jul 2018 12:00:00

30 Jul 2018 12:00:00
```

I need to change only 12:00:00 to 00:00:00 so that it will look alike

```
30 Jul 2018 00:00:00
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the following table structure and table name:

```
MariaDB [freeradius]> SHOW CREATE TABLE users\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: users
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `attribute` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `op` char(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `value` varchar(253) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2001 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

And having this sample data:

```
MariaDB [freeradius]> SELECT * FROM users;
+------+----------+--------------------+------+----------------------+
| id   | username | attribute          | op   | value                |
+------+----------+--------------------+------+----------------------+
| 1980 | 11test   | Cleartext-Password | :=   | 12345                |
| 1981 | 11test   | Expiration         | :=   | 29 Jul 2018 12:00:00 |
| 1982 | 11test   | Simultaneous-Use   | :=   | 1                    |
| 2000 | 22test   | Expiration         | :=   | 30 Jul 2018 12:00:00 |
+------+----------+--------------------+------+----------------------+
4 rows in set (0.000 sec)
```

Assuming all data to be changed has the 'Expiration' attribute, and all has the 12:00:00 timestamp,

the following `UPDATE` command should work:

```
MariaDB [freeradius]> UPDATE users SET value = DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(value, '%e %b %Y %H:%i:%S') - INTERVAL 12 HOUR, '%e %b %Y %H:%i:%S') WHERE attribute = 'Expiration';           
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.001 sec)
Rows matched: 2  Changed: 2  Warnings: 0

MariaDB [freeradius]> SELECT * FROM users;
+------+----------+--------------------+------+----------------------+
| id   | username | attribute          | op   | value                |
+------+----------+--------------------+------+----------------------+
| 1980 | 11test   | Cleartext-Password | :=   | 12345                |
| 1981 | 11test   | Expiration         | :=   | 29 Jul 2018 00:00:00 |
| 1982 | 11test   | Simultaneous-Use   | :=   | 1                    |
| 2000 | 22test   | Expiration         | :=   | 30 Jul 2018 00:00:00 |
+------+----------+--------------------+------+----------------------+
4 rows in set (0.001 sec)
```

You can test it first with a read-only query:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(value, '%e %b %Y %H:%i:%S') - INTERVAL 12 HOUR, '%e %b %Y %H:%i:%S')
FROM users
WHERE attribute = 'Expiration';
```

The exact update operation may change if data is not normalized, or depending on the exact date format, with is not 100% clear (e.g. are 1-digit days of the month starting with a 0?).

This answers your question, but I want to signal some **red flags on your schema**, which would be too important not to mention:

- **There is no reason to keep user's plain text passwords on your database**. I don't need to justify that, there is already plenty of literature that does that for me: http://plaintextoffenders.com/faq/devs Please hash and salt those strings or ask your vendor to do so
- Your question being asked is one of the reasons why **Entity-Attribute-Value is a bad idea in some/many cases**: See https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/93124/eav-is-it-really-bad-in-all-scenarios and how it lead to a self-hanging, as the first answer suggests. More on this: https://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/sql-antipatterns-strike-back/16-EntityAttributeValue_If_you_try_and

Comment: thank you for detailed explanation. & the cmd worked fine :)

Answer (score 2):

If I haven't missed something, a simple [`replace()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace) should do it.

```
UPDATE elbat
       SET value = replace(value, '12:00:00', '00:00:00')
       WHERE attribute = 'Expiration';
```